I want to replace the base URL of a set of specific URLs while preserving the rest of the path using MongoDB's aggregation
I have a set of URLs stored in a MongoDB collection, and you want to replace the base URL of these URLs while preserving the rest of the path and query string. The URLs you want to replace are:
https://url1/uploads/...
https://url2/uploads/...
https://url2/uploads/...

I want these URLs to be converted to:
https://urlForAmazonaws/... - the URL where the images or resources are now hosted.
 input: "$image",
    as: "item",
    in: {
      $replaceOne: {
        input: "$$item.path",
        find: "^https://(url1|url2|url3)/uploads/",
        replacement: "https://urlForAmazonaws/"
      }
    }

I handled the URL replacement like this and expected the final result to be https://urlForAmazonaws/. However, I was surprised that this did not happen. The final result ended up being one of the three original URLs, as nothing changed.

$replaceOne doesn't handle regular expressions so you'll need to use $regexFind along with replaceOne.
Use $regexFind to find IF there is a match AND which part matches:

If there is No match, then $regexFind's result is null (boolean false) then return the original path.
If there is a match, then use the match'ed string to update the path
And merge with the original item if you have other fields in image.

db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "image": {
        $map: {
          input: "$image",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                "path": {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $regexFind: {
                        input: "$$item.path",
                        regex: "^https://(url1|url2|url3)/uploads/"
                      }
                    },
                    then: {
                      $replaceOne: {
                        input: "$$item.path",
                        find: {
                          $getField: {
                            // the `match` field contains the part which matched
                            field: "match",
                            input: {
                              $regexFind: {
                                input: "$$item.path",
                                regex: "^https://(url1|url2|url3)/uploads/"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        replacement: "https://urlForAmazonaws/"
                      }
                    },
                    else: "$$item.path"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)

Mongo Playground
